# Schedule work to happen after someting else triggered

Tags: javascript, scheduling

Is there an easy way in JS to do something like this:

```
var scheduler = ???;
var init;
scheduler.schedule(() => console.log(init)); // does nothing
init = "Hello";
scheduler.start(); // print "Hello" because it was scheduled
scheduler.schedule(() => console.log(" world!")); // instantly print
// "world! " because the scheduler is already active.
```

I also forgot how to call this in CS, what was this called again?

Comment: you mean something like `setTimeout()` does? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: It depends...if you want the scheduler callback to trigger based on a set amount of time elapsing, then use setTimeout() as Yuriy suggests.  If you want it based on some other type of event, then register it with the appropriate event handler.

Comment: what JS environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is event management. Node.js provides [Event Emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html). There's none for browser JS but there's a lot of libs that provide this functionality.

```
const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();

myEmitter.on('event', () => {
  console.log('an event occurred!');
});

myEmitter.emit('event');
```

On the other hand, your code looks more like a [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) (one-time resolve, not multi-trigger). jQuery provides this functionality. I'm not aware of any native implementation. The closest would be a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but promises are "read-only deferreds". They don't expose `resolve`/`reject` after construction.

```
const deferred = $.Deferred();

deferred.then(function(){
  console.log('the deferred resolved!');
});

deferred.resolve(); // logs

// Fires immediately since deferred is already resolved
deferred.then(function(){
  console.log('the deferred resolved already!');
});
```

Comment: But will this 1) discard the first closure after `.emit`. And 2) instantly fire any new closure we schedule after `emit` has been called once in the past.

Comment: @Dorus Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. My brain was blocking somehow, i now see how to do these things again. I'm told that `$.Deffered()` is actually an old school promise. Suddenly i see how these things work again :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a very simple scheduler without a library if you'd like to look at a concept of how that might work

```
"use strict";

class Scheduler {
    constructor(start) {
        this.queue = []
        this.started = !!start
    }

    start() {
        this.started = true
        this.execute()
    }

    stop() {
        this.started = false
    }

    execute() {
        while(this.started && this.queue.length > 0) {
            let fn = this.queue.pop()
            fn()
        }
    }

    schedule(fn, context) {
        if (context) {
            fn = fn.bind(context) 
        }
        this.queue.push(fn)
        this.execute()
    }
}

const scheduler = new Scheduler()
let init
scheduler.schedule(() => console.log(init)) // does nothing
init = "Hello"
scheduler.start() // print "Hello" because it was scheduled
scheduler.schedule(() => console.log(" world!")) // instantly print
// "world! " because the scheduler is already active.
```

Comment: looks good - I was in the middle of writing some very similar code.  You should perhaps allow for what happens if the scheduled function is async?